# Why does this generator return a function instead of a value

Tags: node.js, generator, ecmascript-6, koa

Essentially I'm trying to make an http request with my koa application and was wondering what exactly I would doing wrong

```
var request = require('koa-request');
var beatsGen = beats();
var response1 = beatsGen.next().value;

function *beats (){
  var options = {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/dionoid/koa-request',
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
  };    
  var response = yield request(options);
}
```

When I console log response1 this is what I get

```
respone from beats is function (callback) { 
        _request(uri, options, function (error, response, body) { 
            callback(error, response); 
        }) 
    }
```

I figured response1 would be someType of object containing the body parameter of the callback not the function itself. So why am I getting the function as the generators .next().value?

I'm new to generators and koa so I'm assume I'm making a stupid mistake here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`koa-request` or any other library that returns thunks or promises/thenables for asynchronous calls is meant to be used with a co-routine library like `co` or the `koa` web application framework, which uses `co` to handle generator-based control flow.

ECMAScript 6 generators are not async-aware but ECMAScript 7 will have [async and await](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:async_functions) to handle this natively.

The statement

```
var response1 = beatsGen.next().value;
```

returns the value returned by the first **yield** statement in beats, which is the thunk returned by `request(options)`. A co-routine-aware library will inspect the return value from `generator.next().value` and wait for the callbacks to execute or `then`ables to resolve before resuming the generator body by calling `generator.next()` again.

Such a library is `co`:

```
var request = require('koa-request'),
    co = require('co');

function beats (){ //doesn't have to be a generator function
  var options = {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/dionoid/koa-request',
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'request' }
  };    
  return request(options); //return the thunk
}


co(function *() {
  var response1 = yield beats;
  //use response
})
```

If this is meant to be used with `koa`:

```
app.use(function *() {
  this.body = yield beats();
});
```

BTW, `koa-request` would be better named `co-request` since all co-routine wrappers are prefixed with `co-`.

Comment: Thanks man. Didn't really realize of some of the underlying "magic" that was occurring. Just out of curiosity how would you recommend unit testing in koa. I wouldn't be able to fire the app.use middleware simply from a .exports function call, which is what I've done with express in the pass.

Comment: You could use [co-mocha](https://github.com/blakeembrey/co-mocha) to test generators.